# How do Creationists interpret the faculty of color perception in living beings?

Tags: creation, evolution, creationists, color

Human beings are trichromats meaning that they  have three color receptors in the eye which enable them to see all seven colours of sunlight. Animals are dichromats meaning that they  have only two colour receptors, which restrict their color vision. For instance a human being can easily see a tiger with bright orange colour fur lurking  at a distance against green foliage in daylight.  On the other hand, deer and other animals which are blind to red-green , can hardly spot the same tiger. Evolutionists fail to explain why nature has given colors to the animals if most of them are sensitive only to a limited spectrum of colors. My question is: How do Creationists interpret the faculty of color perception available to human beings vis- a- vis that available to other living beings.

Comment: Same way God created the bat blind but let them rely on echolocation for movement which is one hundred percent accurate. Those dicromat animals are lucky to have a green red vision

Comment: 1. I do not understand how, or why, a Creationist would 'interpret' a faculty. A creature is created with certain faculties. according to the desire of the Creator. Are you asking someone to suggest _why_ the Creator created certain faculties in some creatures and not in others ? 2. Could you substantiate the statement 'Evolutionists fail to explain . . . .  etc'.

Comment: Agree with @NigelJ .  The question is unclear and need to be more specific.  We might as well ask why God gave long nose to elephants, long neck to giraffes, and long beak to pelicans.

Comment: Well, I wanted to pose a question on the issue to the Evolutionists . But, CSE is not the appropriate forum for it. Hence the question to Creationists.

Comment: You could pose the question to "Christian Evolutionists" or [Christians who do not deny evolution](https://biologos.org/articles/famous-christians-who-believed-evolution-is-compatible-with-christian-faith). The moderators sometimes object if you try to cover both groups in one post... so I think this would be a good to make it a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, Dan Fefferman. I am only trying to cut a point across. CSE per se does not bar the ' opposite party' from giving a response. Genesis presents human being as the Crown of Creation. If he has a physical faculty  which no other being has, will that add merit to  the Crown of Creation- concept ?

Comment: I don't understand why anyone, creationist, evolutionist, or atheist, would need to "interpret" colour perception. Bees and butterflies have four colour receptors; what is the interpretation of that? And why can't humans see colour at night, when many animals *can*? Should one interpret that as meaning that God wants us to be attacked by tigers, but only at night?

Comment: Also, birds have four color receptors. See https://answersingenesis.org/birds/birds-eye-view/

Comment: Thanks, Ray Butterworth. Our forefathers hunted during the day and set traps for the night. They lit bonfire to scare away animals during  the night and  hardly needed night vision. As for man-eater tigers, they are an exception rather than a rule. Human beings are not the natural prey of tiger. For that matter, man is not the ' listed' prey of any living being on the land. Of course, things are different once they get into water !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After God created all the sea creatures and all the winged birds he saw that it was good (Genesis 1:20-23).

After God created all the wild animals, livestock, and all the creatures that move upon the ground he saw that it was good (Genesis 1:24-25).

After God created man (in his image and likeness) to rule over all of God's creation, God saw that it was good (Genesis 1:26).

Indeed, all that God created was very good (Genesis 1:31).  Perfect, in other words.

With regard to the sumit of God's creation, the Psalmist reminds us of our relationship to our Creator:

Psalm 139:13-16

> <sup>**13**</sup> For you formed my inward parts; you knitted me together in my mother’s womb. <sup>**14**</sup> I praise you, for I am fearfully and wonderfully made. Wonderful are your works; my soul knows it very well. <sup>**15**</sup> My frame was not hidden from you, when I was being made in secret, intricately woven in the depths of the earth. <sup>**16**</sup> Your eyes saw my unformed substance; in your book were written, every one of them, the days that were formed for me, when as yet there was none of them.

Isaiah 29:16; 45:9; 64:8 sums up the reality of God's creation - God is the potter and we are the clay.  Who are we to question how we have been made?  In God's eyes, it is good, it is very good indeed.

Afterthought, it's just as well we have three colour receptors in order to spot a tiger lurking in the forest.